# Drag and drop download file from browser application onto windows application like Outlook, printer queue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, windows, drag-and-drop

I am trying to download a file while dragging it from browser to windows application like in Outlook, Printer queue etc. The file is getting dropped to desktop or any other file explorer location as expected but when i tried to drop it on a windows application(printer queue), its not working.
I have used dragstart event and jQuery ajax synchronous call. Any help or pointers would be appreciated. Only browser that will be used is Chrome.

In the bottom of this post you can see what I am trying to achieve:
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/box_dnd_download/

Below is the code snippet:

**HTML:**

```
<a id="{{docs[0].documentID}}" draggable="true" ondragstart="angular.element(this).scope().dragOut(this.id, event)">{{docs[0].fileName}}</a>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.dragOut = function(documentId, ev) {

    $.ajax({
        async: false,    
        complete: function(response) {
            var b64Data = response.responseJSON.getDocumentResponse.content;
            var fileName = response.responseJSON.getDocumentResponse.fileName;
            var contentType = response.responseJSON.getDocumentResponse.contentType;



            ev.dataTransfer.setData("DownloadURL",contentType+":"+fileName+":"+"data:"+contentType+";base64,"+b64Data);
            //ev.dataTransfer.setData("DownloadURL", "text/plain:hello.txt:data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ%3D%3D");                        
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            if (xhr.status == 404) {
                xhr.abort();
            }
        },
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'some url',
        data: '',
        headers: {
            withCredentials: true, 
            'Accept': 'application/json', 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    });
};
```

When I try to drop it onto the printer queue for example I get the plus sign but after releasing nothing happens. So dragging onto desktop is done already, what I am trying to do is directly onto windows application.

Reference: https://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/gmail-dragout

Answer (score 0):

You're getting into some pretty tightly controlled OS features here (it's the OS that would handle the drop, not the browser).  But thanks to some interesting coding by google (written for gmail functionality), and some sleuthing by some other developers, this page might help you with what you're looking for:  https://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/gmail-dragout

I did see some discussion mentioning that it works with other applications besides just dragging to the desktop.  But I haven't tried it...

Comment: Actually what is done by the css ninja is what I have running right now. So, I am able to drag a file to my desktop and store it there. But not onto another application directly. In this post: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/box_dnd_download/ he is showing in the bottom what I mean. But he is not explaining how that is achieved actually.

Comment: Fair enough.  It looks like his only works in Chrome and not other browsers.  But it looks like you basically just take his Iteration 3 code, but substitute in the last version of the $.ajax into it...